# why does unset width/height effect object-fit & is there a work around?

Tags: css, sass

## Intro

Whilst using the value unset with the rule object-fit I came across some strange behaviour and wondered if there was a reason/work arround for this issue.

## Example

```
.block {
  &__img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }

  &--portrait {
    .block__img {
      width: unset;
      height: unset;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }
}
```

In this code the height and width of the image are unset even with the `object-fit` style rule (meaning the image keeps its orignal height and width instead of its `cover` width). Why does `unset` effect a rule with a different name?

Is there something going on behind the scenes with `object-fit`and `height` / `width` as the css is rendered?

Comment: can you please make an example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS dimensions of the image are removed from the cascade, but the image still keeps its intrinsic dimensions. So the image's box, i.e. the CSS box generated for the image, is rendered with those intrinsic dimensions (see sections [10.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) and [10.6.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height) of CSS2), and `object-fit: cover` behaves no differently to `object-fit: fill` since the aspect ratio of the box is unchanged.

This is not an issue with the `unset` keyword. The very nature of `object-fit` means that its behavior is directly influenced by the values of `height` and `width`.